# Vue Bootstrap radio buttons are not filled then print webpage

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, vuejs3

Greetings I have project that using vuejs and bootstrap-vue-3. I want possibility to user print data about company. So I created print scss for that. And also made the styles.
I have problem the radio buttons are not filled then I want print the webpage

How it looks like of webpage
[image: webpage before printing]

How it looks like then I want print the page
[image: Printing page]
As you can see(arrows are pointing to) the radio buttons are not filled.

How it looks like in inspector
[image: Radio button in inspector]
and in code

```
<form-group 
   :validator="v$.form.companyType"
    label="Company Type"
    v-if="!isUserParentCompanyAdmin"
>
    <b-form-radio-group
        v-model="form.companyType"
         :options="companyTypes"

     />
 </form-group>
```

If you check vue bootstrap [docs page](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio) the filling working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was/is that in project I am using bootstrap scss not css.
In scss you do not have specific style (-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;)
[image: differences in input-select in css and scss bootstrap]
what is on css so printing of radio buttons can not be done.

How to fix the problem: Two ways

1. I am using Vitejs so you can use [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) this package is adding properties needed for browsers like mention before on postcss thingy.
2. Manually add to @ media print needed property

```scss
.form-check-input:checked[type=radio] {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;   /* Chrome, Safari 6 – 15.3, Edge */
    print-color-adjust: exact;           /* Firefox 97+, Safari 15.4+ */
}
```